# GNU Arm assembler changes ORR into MOVW

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

I'm assembling the following piece of assembler:

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

.section  .text

orr r1, #12800
orr r1, #12801
```

Essentially, just two OR instructions. If I look at the results with `objdump`, I get:

```
bla.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f441 5148   orr.w   r1, r1, #12800  ; 0x3200
   4:   f243 2101   movw    r1, #12801  ; 0x3201
```

The second OR is silently changed into a MOVW! The assembler was run as follows: `arm-none-eabi-gcc -g -Wall -c bla.s` and it didn't show any warnings.

The version of `as` is `GNU assembler version 2.29.51 (arm-none-eabi) using BFD version (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2017-q4-major) 2.29.51.20171128`, running on OSX.

Any idea why the second OR is changed into a MOV?

Comment: My assembler (v2.24.51)  says `Error: invalid constant (3201) after fixup` which makes sense since that is outside of the allowed range.

Comment: @Jester That's what I would expect - maybe I found a bug

Comment: If the assembler **knows** that `r1` had a value of 0, then it could do just the `movm` to get the same result. If not then it could do just the `orr r1, #12801`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: assemblers never make optimizations that assume registers weren't modified *between* instructions, because that can happen when single-stepping with a debugger, or from an interrupt handler.  Some x86 assemblers will do things like optimize `mov rax, 1` to the shorter but otherwise *exactly* equivalent `mov eax,1`.  e.g. NASM does that, but YASM and the GNU assembler don't.

Comment: @Jeroen: I'd recommend [submitting a bug report on GNU binutils](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/describecomponents.cgi?product=binutils), if upgrading to the latest version doesn't fix it (I see the same bug with `arm-none-eabi-as` 2.29.1 on x86-64 Arch Linux, though: same machine-code bytes and disassembly).  If it turns out it's not a bug somehow, then the devs will explain what you did wrong.

Comment: I have just noticed, the disassembly in not thumb.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor You are *technically correct*, since it is thumb2.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor those are thumb instructions, variable length, know as thumb2 extensions.  The first halfword is decode and determined to be a variable length instruction then the second comes along with it.  ARM simply calls them all thumb instructions in their documentation.  Then throw in the unified syntax to make life more painful.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback, I'm in the process of submitting a bugreport (for which I need an account first, which will take some time, apparently). I'll keep you updated.

Comment: The bug-report is here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22773

Comment: bada43421274615d0d5f629a61a60b7daa71bc15 is the correct commit for the bug, it maybe possible the author was thinking about mov instead of orr, but put if instruciton is orr in the if statement.  I cant remember my login for that site and not sure how it works, who can comment, etc...

Comment: Nice, just checked the bug status and they said they fixed it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gas team has confirmed that this is a bug, and has checked in a patch. The Bugzilla entry can be found at https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22773

Answer (score 3):

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

.section  .text

orr r1, #12800
orr r1, #12801
```

arm-none-eabi-as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.29.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-none-eabi'.

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f441 5148   orr.w   r1, r1, #12800  ; 0x3200
   4:   f243 2101   movw    r1, #12801  ; 0x3201
```

Jester has the answer in a comment, you should upvote that.

2.30 was just released a couple of days ago.  It also produces the same results.

Working backward the issues started between 2.27.1 and 2.28.  The tc-arm.c changes for that release were related to the addition of armv8m.  (Cortex-m23 and cortex-m33)

Here is the bug in gas

```
  /* MOV accepts both Thumb2 modified immediate (T2 encoding) and
 UINT16 (T3 encoding), MOVW only accepts UINT16.  When
 disassembling, MOV is preferred when there is no encoding
 overlap.
 NOTE: MOV is using ORR opcode under Thumb 2 mode.  */
  if (((newval >> T2_DATA_OP_SHIFT) & 0xf) == T2_OPCODE_ORR
  && ARM_CPU_HAS_FEATURE (cpu_variant, arm_ext_v6t2_v8m)
  && !((newval >> T2_SBIT_SHIFT) & 0x1)
  && value >= 0 && value <=0xffff)
{
  /* Toggle bit[25] to change encoding from T2 to T3.  */
  newval ^= 1 << 25;
  /* Clear bits[19:16].  */
  newval &= 0xfff0ffff;
  /* Encoding high 4bits imm.  Code below will encode the
     remaining low 12bits.  */
  newval |= (value & 0x0000f000) << 4;
  newimm = value & 0x00000fff;
}
```

The ARM documentation which is over 10 years old now without anyone indicating it is buggy with respect to these instructions.

Yes there is an unused ORR encoding that is used as a MOV encoding, this is typical, not uncommon, in instruction set design.  In no way, shape, or
form does this mean a MOV is an ORR.  Further once the mistake was made to think a MOV was an ORR, then the other MOV encoding was chosen.  I am speechless.

Even worse this has been present for almost a year in the released versions of gas.  How is that possible?

Part of how it is possible is that GCC knows better it encodes this as two separate instructions.

```
orr r1,#0x3200
orr r1,#0x0001
```

So for this to have been found other than the obvious lack of a peer review in the gnu world, would have been for a human to try this.  The ARM immediate encoding rules are easier to remember than the thumb rules.  Folks are always struggling with immediates it is the nature of the beast for RISC instruction sets.  Someone should have hit this by now and someone now has.

Trying on hardware a cortex-m7

test.s

```
.cpu cortex-m7
.syntax unified
.thumb

.thumb_func
.globl test1
test1:
    orr r0,#0x3200
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl test2
test2:
    orr r0,#0x3201
    bx lr
```

run and print out the results

```
hexstring(test1(0x0000));
hexstring(test2(0x0000));
hexstring(test1(0x00FE));
hexstring(test2(0x00FE));
```

gas

```
arm-none-eabi-as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.30
```

result

```
0800005c <test1>:
 800005c:   f440 5048   orr.w   r0, r0, #12800  ; 0x3200
 8000060:   4770        bx  lr

08000062 <test2>:
 8000062:   f243 2001   movw    r0, #12801  ; 0x3201
 8000066:   4770        bx  lr
```

output

```
00003200 
00003201 
000032FE 
00003201
```

A MOV is a MOV not an ORR.

You have found a very nasty bug in gnu assembler, I recommend that you file this bug.  Despite how obvious this bug is I am very curious to see what happens.  I have filed other bugs in the past and they have made excuses rather than fixes, and left the bugs in place.  Please post the link to the ticket as a comment if you choose to file this, so we can all see what they do about it.

bada43421274615d0d5f629a61a60b7daa71bc15 tc-arm.c:23596 is the correct commit and location.

Comment: the armv8m ARM ARM is horrible, the encodings are no longer marked as all thumb variants, armv7m armv8m only, etc...they just say armv8m...

Comment: comment or cut out that if case above and it will error out as not a valid immediate (since you like me always build your own toolchains from sources)...